# How do I move taxonomy, content and content types?

Tags: migrations, 10

I have a Drupal  site which is throw away, but I need to move the taxonomies and content to a clean site, which I have decided to use Drupal 10.

I have the Drupal 9 database loaded into the same database server and set up in the setting.php and I need a way to get it all into the new d10 install.  Migration doesn't seem to recognize my migration yml files. My migration module is on and the migrate module is on. I am wondering if they are not being recognized because it's Drupal 9 to 10 and not coming from Drupal 6 or Drupal 7. Below is one of my yml files in case I have done something wrong.

```yaml
id: group
label: 'Migrate Group'
migration_group: custom_taxonomy
source:
  plugin: d9_taxonomy_term
  vocabulary: group
  key: migrate
destination:
  plugin: entity:taxonomy_term
process:
  vid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: group
  name: name
  parent:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: group
    source: parent_tid
migration_dependencies:
  required: []
```

Comment: I am currently exploring https://understanddrupal.com/lessons/migrating-json-files-drupal/

Comment: What is that file named and where is it placed?

Comment: migrate.group.yml and it's inside my migrations folder in my module

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to drush, can you use the following drush commands.

https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/migrate/

Or you can install this module to export the taxonomy (D8 or D9 Compatible).

https://www.drupal.org/project/term_trans_ex_im

Comment: This is D9 to 10.  when I do drush ms none of import scripts are seen

Comment: First export, then import if commands are available. Go to the source site (D9) and grep for any drush commands with 'export' or 'migrate'

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. None of these solution are for 9/10. the module is only for 8/9 and the drush commands are for Drupal 8.